# How to link to a specific Angular-ui static tab

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I need to link to a specific tab on another view. I have been researching but I am not sure what is the simplest way to go. I am using angular-ui static tabs. There isn't to much information in the tabs so I am not using any type of templates. I am currently using ng-route for my routing, if I need to add ui-router to make this work then that is fine.

Home.html

```
<button>
    Link to Video Email Visit Tab
</button>
```

PatientServices.html

```
<tabset justified="true">
     <tab heading="Online Visit">
        <p>
            Like many other uses of the Internet these days, online visit saves you time by allowing you to receive care.
        </p>
     </tab>

     <tab heading="Video Email Visit">
          <p>
             Meet with your doctor online and get treated for almost any health issue, as long as it isn't a medical emergency.
          </p>
     </tab>
</tabset>
```

ERROR

```
 Error: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'dept-title-tabs"' is not a valid attribute name.
at Error (native)
at Function.n.extend.attr (http://localhost:63193/js/jquery.min.js:4:10701)
at e.attr (http://localhost:63193/js/jquery.imedica.min.js:4:1905)
at n.access (http://localhost:63193/js/jquery.min.js:3:2985)
at n.fn.extend.attr (http://localhost:63193/js/jquery.min.js:4:10224)
at $.fn.(anonymous function) (http://localhost:63193/js/jquery.imedica.min.js:1:3283)
at $.fn.(anonymous function) [as attr] (http://localhost:63193/js/jquery.imedica.min.js:2:5666)
at Object.Attributes.$set (http://localhost:63193/js/angular/angular.js:6721:28)
at http://localhost:63193/js/angular/angular.js:7770:15
at forEach (http://localhost:63193/js/angular/angular.js:330:20)
```

UPDATE ERROR

```
 Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression 'currentTab == 'email'' used with directive 'tab' is non-assignable!
 http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.5/$compile/nonassign?p0=currentTab%20%3D%3D%20'email'&p1=tab
at http://localhost:63193/js/angular/angular.js:63:12
at parentSet (http://localhost:63193/js/angular/angular.js:7585:25)
at parentValueWatch (http://localhost:63193/js/angular/angular.js:7598:23)
at Object.regularInterceptedExpression (http://localhost:63193/js/angular/angular.js:12738:16)
at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:63193/js/angular/angular.js:14125:40)
at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:63193/js/angular/angular.js:14395:24)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:63193/js/angular/angular.js:22827:23)
at HTMLAnchorElement.n.event.dispatch (http://localhost:63193/js/jquery.min.js:3:8066)
at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (http://localhost:63193/js/jquery.min.js:3:4774)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a parameter to link to a specific tab like:

```
<a href="somepage?tab=email">Link to Video Email Visit Tab</a>
```

And then in your controller you could use an object that holds the state for each tab:

```
$scope.tabStates = {};
$scope.tabStates[$location.search().tab || 'online'] = true; //Include default as fallback
```

For each tab you include an `active` expression like:

```
<tabset justified="true">
     <tab heading="Online Visit" active="tabStates['online']">
        <p>
            Like many other uses of the Internet these days, online visit saves you time by allowing you to receive care.
        </p>
     </tab>

     <tab heading="Video Email Visit" active="tabStates['email']">
          <p>
             Meet with your doctor online and get treated for almost any health issue, as long as it isn't a medical emergency.
          </p>
     </tab>
</tabset>
```

Don't forget to inject `$location` into the controller.

Of course you can also use a route param for the tabs to get a url like `yourpage/online` works largely the same way using `$routeParams` instead of `$location`.

Comment: the link works perfect, however something is causing the tab to display wrong, it is showing {{heading}} instead of "Video Email Visit"

Comment: yes, sorry i didnt check that first. just posted it

Comment: Hmm that's caused by some other code and has something to do with the `jquery.imedica.min.js` script. The code Iv'e posted should not cause that error there has to be something else.

Comment: turns out it was a syntax problem. but i do have a new issue. it links correctly but clicking directly on any of the tabs gives this error.